# NSKeyedArchiver on GKScore throwing EXEC_BAD_INSTUCTION

Tags: ios, gamekit, nskeyedarchiver

I am looking into implementing GameKit and cannot get one thing working, it seems quite strange.

If I try to save my GKScore object for later submission using a KeyedArchiver then I am getting a call to encodewithcoder on the class trying to save the GKScore object.

My code is simply,

```
NSData *savedScoreData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:score];
```

I see from various resources on the net that this should be working, but it is not. Looking at the GKScore.h it states it is NSCoding compliant, but my view controller class is having encodewithcoder called on it rather that the GKScore object.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before? I am most puzzled at the moment.